# How to fill daily date gaps in an Access table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called  `Test` with three columns: `Account, Date, and Amount`.
The date looks as follow:

```
Account  Date            Amount
1        25/01/2013      5000
1        20/01/2013      3000
2        25/01/2016      4000
2        20/01/2016      1000
```

Basically, the amount is only recorded when it changes. For example, for `Account 1`, the `Amount` was 3000 from 20/01/2013 to 24/01/2013, then it changed to 5000, and hence, why we have a record.

I want to complete the days from the first record to the last record for each `account`

For example, for `Account 1`, I want to have all days from 20/01/2013 to 24/01/2013 in `Date` and 3000 in the `Amount`

I know this is a tricky one, your help is much appreciated. Many thanks !!

Comment: You can do this with a calendar table.  Without one, it really isn't feasible.

Comment: How can I even do that? The challenge is every account has a different date range!

Comment: @Gustav.  I don't think this should be closed as duplicate.  Creating a list of dates is only part of the problem - one which the SQL in your linked answer looks like it does.  The other part is to change the `Amount` value where the date changes per `Account` which the link doesn't answer.

Comment: @Gustav, thank you for looking at my question, but as Darren said, this is simply a different question. while I do need to generate a date range, it will grouped by customer, then there is another part to it, which is filled the amount column. Thank you

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: Reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You just had to find the first and last dates. Anyway:

First, find min and max dates:

```
SELECT 
    Account, 
    Min(tblProvider.[Entry Date]) AS FirstDate, 
    Max(tblProvider.[Entry Date]) AS LastDate
FROM 
    Test
GROUP BY 
    Account;
```

Save this as *qDateMinMax*.

Then create the factor query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Thousands]+[Hundreds]+[Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 
    1000*Abs([Mille].[id] Mod 10) AS Thousands, 
    100*Abs([Centa].[id] Mod 10) AS Hundreds, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
    Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
FROM 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca,
    MSysObjects AS Centa, 
    MSysObjects AS Mille;
```

Save this as *qdxFactor*.

Now, assemble these:

```
SELECT 
    qDateMinMax.Account, 
    qDateMinMax.FirstDate, 
    qDateMinMax.LastDate, 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]) AS OtherDate,
        (Select Last(Amount) 
        From Test 
        Where Test.Account = qDateMinMax.Account 
        And Test.[Entry Date] = qDateMinMax.LastDate) As LastAmount
FROM 
    qDateMinMax, 
    qdxFactor
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]) <= [LastDate]
ORDER BY 
    qDateMinMax.Account, 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]);
```

For the *median*:

```
SELECT 
    qDateMinMax.Account, 
    qDateMinMax.FirstDate, 
    qDateMinMax.LastDate, 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]) AS OtherDate, 
        (Select (Min(Amount) + Max(Amount)) / 2
        From Test 
        Where Test.Client = qDateMinMax.Account 
        And Test.[Entry Date] Between qDateMinMax.FirstDate And qDateMinMax.LastDate) AS MedAmount
FROM 
    qDateMinMax, 
    qdxFactor
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]) <= [LastDate]
ORDER BY 
    qDateMinMax.Account, 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]);
```

To group by year-month:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    qDateMinMax.Account, 
    Format([FirstDate],"yyyymm") AS FirstYM, 
    Format([LastDate],"yyyymm") AS LastYM, 
    Format(DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]),"yyyymm") AS YM, 
        (Select (Min(Amount) + Max(Amount)) / 2
        From Test 
        Where Test.Client = qDateMinMax.Account 
        And Test.[Entry Date] Between qDateMinMax.FirstDate And qDateMinMax.LastDate) AS MedAmount
FROM 
    qDateMinMax, 
    qdxFactor
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]) <= [LastDate];
```

To include the last amount:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    qDateMinMax.Account, 
    Format([FirstDate],"yyyymm") AS FirstYM, 
    Format([LastDate],"yyyymm") AS LastYM, 
    Format(DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate]),"yyyymm") AS YM, 
        (Select (Min(Amount) + Max(Amount)) / 2
        From Test 
        Where Test.Client = qDateMinMax.Account 
        And Test.[Entry Date] Between qDateMinMax.FirstDate And qDateMinMax.LastDate) AS MedAmount, 
        (Select Amount
        From Test 
        Where Test.Client = qDateMinMax.Account 
        And Test.[Entry Date] =LastDate) AS LastAmount
FROM 
    qDateMinMax, 
    qdxFactor
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[FirstDate] <= [LastDate];
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great apart from issue; The amount I want is not the minimum amount, but rather the amount each record up until the next date. For example, there is more record on 01/01/2000 with amount of 1000, then one record on 20/01/2000 with an amount of 2000. I therefore want the amount from 01/01/2000 to 19/01/2000 to be 1000, and so on. Many thanks again Gustav

Comment: On additional question (but potentially tricky). How can I get the median for the amount, grouped by account and month/year? I know there is some help to get the median on here, but it does not show how to group them. I would be grateful if you can help me with this. Thank you !

Comment: You should be able to obtain the median amount - see edited answer please. To group by year/month, use this query for yet a query where you group as needed. Or open a new question with some sample data.

Comment: There is a mistake ! The days are limited too 100 only for each account) !! Could you please help!

Comment: I must say, your sample data wasn't very representative, and that's all we have. The _qdxFactor_ query can easily be expanded to return 10^3 or 10^4 records. The field names are descriptive, so you should be able to figure it out yourself. If not, drop a note, and I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: No :( The maxim dates I have for each account is 5 years ( 5*365) so the maximum number of days is 1825

Comment: Edited. But with that many days, this technique may be too slow. Depends.

Comment: Thank you, I know, but I cannot think of a better solution. I am happy to leave it running over a few hours. Many thanks again Gustav !

Comment: OK, Then please mark as answered and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Hello, the median table is great, I just need to have the amount for each date showing in it and it would be my final table. However,  when I try add it, it is asking me to group by, which will mess up the result. I would be grateful if you can add it for me, and I promise this would be it. You have been incredibly helpful, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Another thing, the median table should be by account and by month! It is not by month!

Comment: To group by month, you can use Distinct - see edited answer, please. I'm not sure what you mean by "have the amount for each date" as there are no amounts for all the artificial dates. Anyway, you should have got the ideas and possible methods by now to be able to make your final adjustments.

Comment: So the amount I am looking for is the amount from the original table for the available records, plus since we filled up the missing dates, also to fill up the amount according to the logic above (the amount for the missing date is what the same amount as the latest available date)

Comment: So I am looking to have all of these in one table; Account, date, amount, median. Apologies if I am begin a pain. I am very new to this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, but a final edit has been added. I don't think we can pull the leg any longer.